# How to load .txt file into separate .html files? c++

Tags: html, c++, html-parsing

I need to read an HTML file and then separate specific parts of it into individuals HTML files.

For example:

```
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
<ul>something 123</ul>
<p>something else 123</p>
<p>blabla</p>
<table>example</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything between `<ul>` and `</ul>` should be saved in another HTML file, same with everything between `<p>` and `</p>.`

I need to use `<fstream>` library, and I do not know how to use vectors, so I need to do this probably without them unless there's a simple solution.

The main problem, for now, is, how to read a file until a string is found? 
I mean, for example - `string table = "<table>"` is found and then the program is saving everything after `<table>` until it finds `string end_table = "</table>"`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There’s no effort to try to do this yourself so most likely there won’t be much help here since it will be seen as “do this for me.” You know how to open files? Read lines from them? Compare strings? Write files? That’s all you basically need. When you have that done and if you run into specific problems you can ask for help with them.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Maybe I should've said it differently - I just want to know how to read a file using ifstream until it finds those special strings.

Comment: Improve tags, content, code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to locate the beginning and ending body tag with the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   string line = "some line with <body> in it";
   string bodytag = "<body>";

   if(line.find(bodytag) != string::npos) {
     cout << "found" << endl;
   }

   return 0;
 }
```

Then just read lines in from the file until you find the `<body>` tag and output them until you find the `</body>` tag. You might need to modify this if content that needs to be saved appears after the opening body tag or before the closing body tag on the same line. Your input doesn't contain this, so this isn't likely a problem.

Comment: Thank you, it helped! :)